Why was the "Labs" section of the left hand menu removed?
I've noticed that Discussions and Jobs no longer appear under the "Labs" section on the left hand menu; they were lists under the "labs" section this morning. To ask a "silly" question; why? Both products, when you visit them, show they are still part of the "Labs" initiative.
Jobs is still not available outside of the USA, and Discussions is a burning dumpster truck. These features getting more prominent places, is a terrible idea when one isn't available the most people, and the other is more likely to them advertise porn, illegal streams, or phishing websites.
Can you, perhaps finish products before we start fully promoting them to the navigation menu, Stack Overflow?
You can see what the left navigation menu looked like before (thanks chivracq) and after.

How does one even find the sites without the sidebar?

They were in the side bar before, @JourneymanGeek , but under a "labs" section; that they aren't listed under that now implies completion of those products (to me).

Jobs also still doesn't understand what states are... so even for US users it's hardly useful for anything outside of maybe fully remote jobs.

I mean, are they linked somewhere else?

@JourneymanGeek Not in the site navigation. You can probably find links for these features in announcements (and/or other posts that discuss them on meta). But the left sidebar is the only official navigation to them, AFAIK.

I mean... if they're as done as they're gonna be then they are complete, no? Neither has received meaningful updates in a year

Discussions and jobs were always on the sidebar for me

Maybe this means that they are no longer experiments and are somehow considered "successful" and are now permanent features

@Starship-OnDiscussionsStrike "Discussions and jobs were always on the sidebar for me" yes, they always were there. But classified under the "Labs" hading, as in this screenshot (taken from here). They were in the left sidebar before, and they are in the left sidebar now. The difference the lack of "Labs".

Here is a better (full) Screenshot of the old 'Left-Nav'. (I just took it myself, => you can reuse it if you want to add it to the Qt itself... (no need to credit me), maybe with also a Screenshot of the "new" Layout next to it for comparison...) // And the 'Labs' Section/Link was pointing to this page...

It follows the pattern of iteratively applying small changes to the site that have been popping up numerous times the last few weeks already. Apparently labs had to go. Their site, their UI, their plan, their release schedule.

@Gimby "Apparently labs had to go." Well, maybe not, you still/now(?) have a direct Link to 'Labs' under 'Products' in the Top-Navbar, with more or less the same URL (referral added compared to the "old" URL, but both land on the same page).

Hey Ya'll, thanks for calling attention to this. The labs header was accidentally removed yesterday when folks were doing some cleanup of a lot of dead code.  I'm reverting right now to add it back in.

Moving comment to answer, but thanks for calling attention to this. The labs header was accidentally removed yesterday when folks were doing some cleanup of a lot of dead code. I just reverted that section back in.
Should be back coming  to a production environment near you in the next 5 or so minutes.

